# Is that correct to split the i18n dictionary by translation value instead of business logic?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

For example - my application has a different types of entities: person and client.

Application has the dictionary, containing labels and translations for a couple of languages.

```
const en = {
  firstName: 'First name',
  lastName: 'Last name',
  address: 'Address'
};

const ru = {
  firstName: 'Имя',
  lastName: 'Фамилия',
  address: 'Адрес'
}

const dictionary = createDictionary({ en, ru });
```

As you can see there is no difference between labels for `person` or `client` if they have the same translation.

Should I separate the labels by entity type?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same word and it translates as the same word, there's no need to differentiate. You probably have many places in your app where you translate the word "Okay" on a button, and you don't need to differentiate every single "Okay" button to end up with 200 separate translations which are all identical.

Having said that, in some languages words do translate differently depending on context, probably especially in the area of people's names, honourifics and pronouns. Therefore it's important that your translators understand the *context* of the translation. This is a bit hard in the format you chose, but in [gettext PO files](http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html), this could look something like:

```
#: signup-form.html:42 admin/user-details.html:69
msgid "First name"
msgstr "Имя"
```

Now, say, your Japanese translator may come to you and say that "First name" in the context of addressing the user directly, and in the context of an admin view, should really be differentiated for politeness. Again, in PO files you could add context:

```
#: signup-form.html:42
msgctxt "Label addressing the user in signup form"
msgid "First name"
msgstr "お客様の名"

#: admin/user-details.html:69
msgctxt "Label for user data in admin view"
msgid "First name"
msgstr "名"
```

Those are now two separate strings that can be translated separately.

So, the important thing here is to have *a* technical solution to disambiguate if necessary, to provide enough context and awareness to translators, and to have a working feedback mechanism between translators and programmers to add disambiguations where necessary. Programmers shouldn't overzealously disambiguate needlessly, since they often can't anticipate where it's *really* necessary.